# How to edit markdown help

Tags: support

I always forget the specifics of the cool feature where adding a lowercase **s**, **m** or **l** at the end of the imgur link before the ".png" will change the size of the image.  As discussed here: [How to make pictures smaller?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/how-to-make-pictures-smaller)

Can this info be added to the markdown help page here? https://robotics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images

Is this page something only admins (and not moderators) can edit?

Comment: Yes, this is a part of the network-wide Markdown Editing Help page, so only staff (specifically, the developers) can make changes to it. if you want to suggest a change to it, you should probably ask on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) instead.